# If / else condition inside Nested foreach loop

Tags: c#

I am trying to check for specific condition using if statements inside the nested `foreach` loop, but there comes to a point where one of the object in the list will  not match the first condition. The problem that I am having is if i put an else with that first if condition, it will make all of my objects in the list false even tough there is a match for each one except for the last one.

```
public void ReserveRoom(List<ReservationType> reservation)
{
         List<ReservationType> RequestReservation = new List<ReservationType>();

        RequestReservation = reservation;   //List that contains the test cases.

        string reservationid = "0001";
        int number = int.Parse(reservationid);
         int count = 0;
    foreach (ReservationType requestReservation in RequestReservation)
    {
        List<String> DateList = CreateDateList(requestReservation.StartDate, requestReservation.numDays);

        foreach (Inventory inventory in RoomInventory)
        {
            if (requestReservation.hotelId == inventory.HotelId)
            {
                if (requestReservation.roomType == inventory.RoomType)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < DateList.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (DateList[i] == inventory.Date  && inventory.Quantity > 0)
                        {
                            count++;
                            //Console.Write(requestReservation.customerId + ": " + inventory.Date + ": " + count + Environment.NewLine);
                        }
                    }

                    if (requestReservation.numDays == count)
                    {
                        requestReservation.result = ReservationType.ReservationResultType.Success;
                        count = 0;
                    }

                    foreach (String dt in DateList)
                    {
                        if (dt.Equals( inventory.Date))                            
                            inventory.Quantity--;                            
                    }

                    foreach (Hotels h in LHotels)
                    {
                        foreach (Room rm in h.RoomList)
                        {
                             if (requestReservation.hotelId == h.HotelId && requestReservation.roomType == rm.RoomType)                                 
                                 requestReservation.cost = (requestReservation.numDays * rm.Rate);                                 
                        }
                    }                          
                }
            }
            else
            {
              requestReservation.result = ReservationType.ReservationResultType.UnknownHotelId;
            }

        }
        number++;
    }
}
```

output that im trying to achieve:

```
<ReservationType>
<hotelId>2345</hotelId>
<StartDate>20160905</StartDate>
<numDays>1</numDays>
<customerId>00001</customerId>
<roomType>KB</roomType>
<reservationId>0002</reservationId>
<cost>325</cost>
<result>Success</result>
</ReservationType>
<ReservationType>
<hotelId>2345</hotelId>
<StartDate>20160905</StartDate>
<numDays>4</numDays>
<customerId>00002</customerId>
<roomType>KB</roomType>
<reservationId>0003</reservationId>
<cost>1300</cost>
<result>Success</result>
</ReservationType>
<ReservationType>
<hotelId>2345</hotelId>
<StartDate>20160905</StartDate>
<numDays>5</numDays>
<customerId>00003</customerId>
<roomType>KB</roomType>
<reservationId>0004</reservationId>
<cost>1625</cost>
<result>Success</result>
</ReservationType>
<ReservationType>
<hotelId>2345</hotelId>
<StartDate>20160907</StartDate>
<numDays>3</numDays>
<customerId>00004</customerId>
<roomType>KB</roomType>
<reservationId>0005</reservationId>
<cost>975</cost>
<result>Success</result>
</ReservationType>
<ReservationType>
<hotelId>2345</hotelId>
<StartDate>20160909</StartDate>
<numDays>4</numDays>
<customerId>00005</customerId>
<roomType>KB</roomType>
<reservationId>0006</reservationId>
<cost>1300</cost>
<result>Success</result>
</ReservationType>
<ReservationType>
<hotelId>2345</hotelId>
<StartDate>20160906</StartDate>
<numDays>5</numDays>
<customerId>00006</customerId>
<roomType>KB</roomType>
<cost>0</cost>
<result>RoomNotAvailable</result>
</ReservationType>
<ReservationType>
<hotelId>7890</hotelId>
<StartDate>20160905</StartDate>
<numDays>1</numDays>
<customerId>00007</customerId>
<roomType>QB</roomType>
<reservationId>00006</reservationId>
<cost>400</cost>
<result>Success</result>
</ReservationType>
<ReservationType>
<hotelId>7890</hotelId>
<StartDate>20160905</StartDate>
<numDays>1</numDays>
<customerId>00008</customerId>
<roomType>QB</roomType>
<cost>0</cost>
<result>RoomNotAvailable</result>
</ReservationType>
<ReservationType>
<hotelId>7890</hotelId>
<StartDate>20160905</StartDate>
<numDays>4</numDays>
<customerId>00009</customerId>
<roomType>QB</roomType>
<reservationId>00007</reservationId>
<cost>400</cost>
<result>Success</result>
</ReservationType>
<ReservationType>
<hotelId>7890</hotelId>
<StartDate>20170905</StartDate>
<numDays>1</numDays>
<customerId>00010</customerId>
<roomType>QB</roomType>
<cost>0</cost>
<result>RoomNotAvailable</result>
</ReservationType>
<ReservationType>
<hotelId>7890</hotelId>
<StartDate>20160915</StartDate>
<numDays>5</numDays>
<customerId>00011</customerId>
<roomType>QB</roomType>
<reservationId>00007</reservationId>
<cost>500</cost>
<result>Success</result>
</ReservationType>
<ReservationType>
<hotelId>7890</hotelId>
<StartDate>20160925</StartDate>
<numDays>10</numDays>
<customerId>00012</customerId>
<roomType>QB</roomType>
<cost>0</cost>
<result>RoomNotAvailable</result>
</ReservationType>
<ReservationType>
<hotelId>7890</hotelId>
<StartDate>20160907</StartDate>
<numDays>3</numDays>
<customerId>00013</customerId>
<roomType>QB</roomType>
<reservationId>00008</reservationId>
<cost>300</cost>
<result>Success</result>
</ReservationType>
<ReservationType>
<hotelId>7890</hotelId>
<StartDate>20160909</StartDate>
<numDays>3</numDays>
<customerId>00014</customerId>
<roomType>KB</roomType>
<reservationId>00009</reservationId>
<cost>600</cost>
<result>Success</result>
</ReservationType>
<ReservationType>
<hotelId>7890</hotelId>
<StartDate>20160905</StartDate>
<numDays>1</numDays>
<customerId>00015</customerId>
<roomType>AB</roomType>
<cost>0</cost>
<result>UnknownRoomType</result>
</ReservationType>
<ReservationType>
<hotelId>8888</hotelId>
<StartDate>20160905</StartDate>
<numDays>1</numDays>
<customerId>00016</customerId>
<roomType>DB</roomType>
<cost>0</cost>
<result>UnknownHotelId</result>
</ReservationType>
```

The results im getting : and this is for every object. unknownhotelid

```
<ReservationType>
<hotelId>2345</hotelId>
<StartDate>20160907</StartDate>
<numDays>3</numDays>
<customerId>00004</customerId>
<roomType>KB</roomType>
<reservationId>0005</reservationId>
<cost>975</cost>
<result>UnknownHotelId</result>
```

Comment: Where did you put the `else` statement?

Comment: This algorithm has a terrible runtime complexity. There are better approaches. Is this a homework/coursework exercise or actual production software?

Comment: Your question is not clear - there's no way to tell which `if` statement you are talking about. Please consider rewording, or adding the `else` statement.  Also note method parameter - reservation - is not used anywhere in your code

Comment: I edited to see where i put my else statement. @dai, what other methods is better to approach this?

Comment: Any chance you could explain what the output of this method is? I think I agree with @dai, and I think this could be cleaned up a lot, but I'm not 100% comfortable I understand what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Loops-within-loops to find matching elements (i.e. `O(n^m)` can be improved by using hashtables for `O(1)` lookup).

Comment: i display the output that im trying to achieve.  and the results that im getting right now. the problem is the else, the moment it does not match, it goes to the else.